# why does Svelte warn me about needed props that I pass to component?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I get this warning from svelte:

`Modal.svelte:38 <Modal> was created with unknown prop 'setIsOpen'`

it's true that I don't include an export statement for this prop, intentionally.
but this is an essential prop, that I pass to a composed component, using $$restProps, like so:

```
<ModalInner on:close
        {lastSuccess}
        {errorLocation}
        {...$$restProps}
>
    <slot></slot>
</ModalInner>
```

I think this warning is erroneous. any way to prevent it?

Comment: I have similar problems using <svelte:component this=${blah} {...$paramsStore}, where all components get the same props but some don't use them. Wish there was a way I could just disable the warning for just this component instance.